# Windows 8 will not start

Tags: windows-8, hibernate

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8 installed on my i3 laptop.

Suddenly, Windows 8 stopped booting.

I tried `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2` which tells me that `could not wake up from hibernate`

Comment: Sounds like a Windows issue. Any reason to think it is caused by Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your windows 8 is not booting

You will need a windows 8 repair disk or usb, or  windows 8 install disk.
Boot from the repair disk, and select the startup repair option 
( which says 'fix problems which are preventing windows from startup')
and repair it.
mayble it will fix it.

It could also result in windows writing over the grub, so that you may have to reinstall grub. [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is an excellent tool for doing this.